# Python (pyspark) - Function decorator for UDF definition

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, python-decorators

I'm actually trying to define UDF with accumulator inside it. Accumulator is used to save exceptions from *my_function* for later. I come up with a definition of udf with some arguments (returnType, accumulator).
I'd like to make it a bit more readable and reusable. How could I define a decorator function with the code below ?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.accumulators import AccumulatorParam
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructField, IntegerType, StructType
from pyspark.sql import Row

data = [
    Row(word="foo", number=7),
    Row(word="bar", number=13)]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("word", StringType(), True),
    StructField("number", IntegerType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

#### Creation of my custom accumulator

```
class ListParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, v):
        return []

    def addInPlace(self, variable, value):
        variable.append(value)
        return variable

accum = spark.sparkContext.accumulator([], ListParam())
```

#### Definition of my udf

```
def accumulator_udf(accumulator, returnType):
    def my_function(x):
        y = None
        try:
            y = (x / (x - 7))
        except Exception as e:
            accumulator.add(dict([('errorType', str(e)), ('Data', x)]))
        return y

    return F.udf(my_function, returnType)

my_udf = accumulator_udf(accumulator=element_div_acc, returnType=IntegerType())
```

#### Result

```
df.select(my_udf(df.number)).show()

  +---------------+
  |div_one(number)|
  +---------------+
  |           null|
  |              2|
  +---------------+

print(accum.value)
> [[{'errorType': 'integer division or modulo by zero', 'Data': 7}], []]
```

#### What I've tried

After few readings, I found this post (https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/)  which helped but it'm stuck with a NameError

```
def accumulator_udf(accumulator, returnType):
    def func_wrapper(func):
            return F.udf(func, returnType)
    return func_wrapper

accum = spark.sparkContext.accumulator([], ListParam())
@accumulator_udf(accumulator=accum , returnType=IntegerType())
def my_function(x):
    y = None
    try:
        y = (x / (x - 7))
    except Exception as e:
        accumulator.add(dict([('errorType', str(e)), ('Data', x)]))
    return y

df.select(my_function(df.number)).show()
```

When trying this implementation, I have the following error :

```
NameError: global name 'accumulator' is not defined
```

How could I manage to be able to access 'accumulator' ?

Thanks !